# AR model with MATLAB

Tags: statistics, matlab, approximation

I'm using the following code taken from MATLAB documentation to estimate the parameters of an ARMA model:

> `y = sin([1:300]') + 0.5 * randn(300, 1);`
>   `y = iddata(y);`
>   `mb = ar(y, 4, 'burg');`

At this point, if if I type `mb` what I get is this:

> Discrete-time IDPOLY model:
>   A(q)y(t) = e(t)
>   A(q) = 1 - 0.2764 q^-1 + 0.2069 q^-2 + 0.4804 q^-3 + 0.1424 q^-4
>   Estimated using AR ('burg'/'now') from data set y
>   Loss function 0.314965 and FPE 0.323364
>   Sampling interval: 1

How can I use the variable `mb` I obtained to generate samples with those coefficients?
`mb` doesn't look like a vector.
In particular, how can I handle missing data?

Answer (score 2):

Use: `sim(mb,input)`

More info about [`sim`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/sim.html) and also [here](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/ident/sim.html#1478484):

> Simulate linear models.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> y = sim(m,ue)
>
> [y, ysd] = sim(m,ue,init)
>
> **Description**
>
> *m* is an arbitrary idmodel object.
>
> *ue* is an iddata object, containing inputs only. The number of input
>   channels in ue must either be equal to the number of inputs of the
>   model m, or equal to the sum of the number of inputs and noise sources
>   (= number of outputs). In the latter case the last inputs in ue are
>   regarded as noise sources and a noise-corrupted simulation is
>   obtained. The noise is scaled according to the property
>   m.NoiseVariance in m, so in order to obtain the right noise level
>   according to the model, the noise inputs should be white noise with
>   zero mean and unit covariance matrix. If no noise sources are
>   contained in ue, a noise-free simulation is obtained.